# I need to insert a array value in the data base

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter framework.I have a array of id that is to be saved in service_id column in my table. I need to store a array of id in my table. my table structure is as given below.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `addservice` (
  `employee_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `service_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I wrote a controller for this like:

```
class service extends CI_Controller
{
public function services()
    {

    $id = $this->session->userdata('employee');
    $id_array = json_encode($this->input->post("services"));
    $data_to_store=array('employee_id'=>$id,'service_id'=>$id_array));
    $this->add_service_model->save($data_to_store);
    $data['addservice'] =    $this->add_service_model->get_addservices();   
            $data['main_content'] = 'admin/service_limitation/newview';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);  

    }
}
 I used json_encode function. I dont get any error but i am getting a white screen. I wrote a view file where i post my id as check box.In this view file i am posting the service_id as a array and post them to my controller. My view file are:
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="header">Service id</th>
                <th class="yellow header headerSortDown">Service name </th>
                <th class="green header">Service catogary</th>
                <th class="red header">Service tax</th>
                <th class="red header">Service length</th>
                <th class="red header">Service price</th>
                <th class="red header">Actions</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <?php
              foreach($service as $row)
              {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['id'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['service_name'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['category'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['service_tax'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['service_length'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['service_price'].'</td>';
                echo '<td class="crud-actions">
                 <input type="checkbox" value="'.$row['id'].'" name="services[]"/>

                </td>';
                echo '</tr>';
              }
              ?>      
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

my model file

```
class mymodel extends CI_Model{

public function get_addservices()
    {
    $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('addservice');
    $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array(); 
    }
        public function save($data)
    {
    $insert = $this->db->insert('addservice', $data);
        return $insert;

    }
}
```

here in this file, i used a function save to save data to my table

Comment: Where is your model function???

Comment: i edited my post.. please kindly refer it

Comment: What is the error showing ?

Comment: I am getting a white screen.. i find no values inserted into my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `json_encode` from input post and use for loop to get value of array

**Controller**

```
public function services()
$id = $this->session->userdata('employee');
$id_array = $this->input->post("services");
for ($i = 0; $i < count($id_array); $i++) {// add for loop here
    if(isset($id_array[$i])&& $id_array[$i]!=""){
    $data_to_store = array('employee_id' => $id, 'service_id' => $id_array[$i]);
    $this->add_service_model->save($data_to_store);
   }
}
$data['addservice'] = $this->add_service_model->get_addservices();
$data['main_content'] = 'admin/service_limitation/newview';
$this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
}
```

Comment: Error Number: 1048

Column 'service_id' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `addservice` (`employee_id`, `service_id`) VALUES ('4534', NULL)

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\elfanto\elfanto_billing\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Comment: i do not get the NULL error now. but my values are not inserted. it could insert only 1 id

Comment: What is the value of `$this->input->post("services")`

Comment: And now your value start insert into your database!!

Comment: $this->input->post("services") is used to get the id posted in a form that i have in my view

Comment: what is the value of it in controler `print_r($this->input->post("services"))`

Comment: it holds the service id that i choose in view page and post its value.i get those values in my controller and save them to db

Comment: but i could insert only the last value i choose